# What happens in a 'for in' cycle if object property does not exist in javascript?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

If I have

```
for(var key in object.foo) { ... }
```

but foo does not exist, what does happens? I mean, the cycle stops, loop or what?

Comment: Have you considered writing a test case and looking to see what happens?

Comment: Nothing happens :)

Comment: No way to hide nothing to you... It is part of a larger problem and I was trying to get what is supposed to happen in a case like this

Comment: That's like saying `for(key in undefined)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

0 iteration.
Nothing there to loop.No error. Simply.
[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fbeyy/33/)

```
var myObj1 = {};
myObj1["cz"] = "Czech";
myObj1["en"] = "English";
myObj1["de"] = "German";

for (var key in myObj1.foo) {
    console(key + " is the abbreviation for " + myObj1[key]);
}
```

//no output in console

Answer (score 1):

Nothing happen because there is no items to loop on. It is just a loop in `undefined`  :P